# How to open HTML file as UTF-8 for parsing it?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse an html file using BeautifulSoup with python 3, but I get UTF-8 decode error. I've tried adding the option to open file decoding as UTF-8 but the error still appears.

How to fix this?

This is what I have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("file.html") as fp:                      
    unicode_html = fp.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')  

soup = BeautifulSoup( unicode_html)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):          
> /usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode        
>
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) 
>
>  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 30287: invalid continuation byte
> ```

Comment: Your file isn't encoded in `UTF-8`

Comment: Then why is the error?

Comment: As background, there are different forms of character encoding. `bs4` assumes `utf-8`, but your text isn't, which is why you got the error. (So making `utf-8` explicit wouldn't help!) You need to determine the encoding, which [isn't always easy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file). Can you share the source URL?

Comment: Why not open the file with `open(filename, encoding='utf8')`? There is no reason to decode text files manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default mode for `open()` is `rt` which is read in text mode. Use `rb` to read in binary mode. At the moment, the decoder is being fed decoded text which it may not like too much.

The error of `UnicodeDecodeError` appears to happen possibly due to the output device (like a console) not supporting the encoding.

With a command prompt, the error output is

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

which appears more correct error. I was also using a shebang of

> #!/usr/bin/env python3 -X utf8

which makes Python output UTF-8 to get the `AttributeError`.

Change the line:

```
with open("file.html") as fp:
```

to

```
with open("file.html", "rb") as fp:
```

Comment: Thansk so much Michael. That was the solution. After you suggestion is not even needed the line unicode_html=...